# ping ipv6 address Address family for hostname not supported

Tags: ping, centos-7

using ifconfig to see eth0 ipv4 and ipv6 addresses. ping ipv4 is ok, but ping ipv6 results in:

[image: ping fails]

Comment: Which iputils version do you use? (run `ping -V` to see). I fixed this in commit [db77fb5](https://github.com/iputils/iputils/commit/db77fb5b910f3865c158e761392bf7fc97c66ffa), which belongs to s20180629 release. For more info see also [#99](https://github.com/iputils/iputils/issues/99).

Answer (score 0):

This means, that the site is not resolving in an ip6 address, e.g. github.com has the same:

```
$ ping -4 github.com
PING github.de (140.82.114.18) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lb-140-82-114-18-iad.github.com (140.82.114.18): icmp_seq=1 ttl=39 time=205 ms
64 bytes from lb-140-82-114-18-iad.github.com (140.82.114.18): icmp_seq=2 ttl=39 time=228 ms
^C
--- github.de ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 205.156/216.759/228.363/11.603 ms

$ ping -6 github.com
ping: github.de: Address family for hostname not supported
```